# past simple or past perfect progressive

Tags: past-simple, past-perfect-continuous

This is an example from a book: "I had been teaching English in Japan when the earthquake hit." To me this means that I had been teaching for a while at the time the earthquake hit. If I just want to express that at the time of the earthquake I was employed as a teacher in Japan, regardless of how long I had been working there can I say "I taught English in Japan when the earthquake hit"?

Comment: If all I wanted to say was that I was employed as a teacher in Japan when the earthquake hit, I would say, "I was a teacher in Japan when the earthquake hit", or "I was teaching in Japan when the earthquake hit."

Comment: If you take the sentence by itself, the use of the past perfect is awkward. But if the sentence was part of a narrative in which the author was reflecting on some past experience, and was about to continue the story, it might be perfectly acceptable.